# On the equation $\sigma(m)=105k$ over odd integers $m\geq 1$, and the deficiency of its solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-sum

In this post we denote the sum of positive divisors of a natural $n\geq 1$ as $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d.$$

We consider integers $m\geq 1$ and $k\geq 1$ where $m\equiv 1\text{ mod }2$ (thus $m$ is an odd integer) that are solutions $(m,k)$ of the equation $$\sigma(m)=105\cdot k.\tag{1}$$

**Example.** The first few solutions of $(1)$ satisfying previous requirements  are $(m,k)=(377,4),(419,4),(695,8),(767,8),(779,8)$ and $(839,8)$.

**Definition.** We denote the set of all $m$'s being $(m,k)$ a solution as $\mathcal{M}$. That is

$$\mathcal{M}=\{\text{odd integers }m\geq 1\text{ s.t. }\sigma(m)=105k,\text{ for some integer }k\geq 1\}.$$

> **Question 1.** Prove or refute these statements
>
> 1) *If* $m\in\mathcal{M}$ **then** $m$ *is deficient* (this last condition  means that $\sigma(m)<2m$).
>
> 2) *Let* 
>   $$\mathcal{D}=\{\text{integers }m\in\mathcal{M}\text{ s.t. }\sigma(m)<2m\},$$
>   *thus it denotes the set of odd integers* $m\geq 1$ *satisfying that* $(m,k)$ *is a solution of* $(1)$ *and that* $m$ *is a deficient number.* **Then** $\mathcal{D}$ *has infinitely many elements*.
>
> **Many thanks.**

I was inspired in my experiments to state the conjectures *1* and *2*. As aside remark we can to prove that on assumption that $M$ is an odd perfect number, then doesn't safisfy $(1)$, that is $\sigma(M)=105k$ is an absurd (when we assume that there exists an odd perfect number $M$).

Comment: I add that there is an article from Wikipedia for *Deficient number*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ The smallest counterexample is $12\ 285$. There are many more.

$2)$ Every prime of the form $105k-1$ does the job, and there are infinite many such primes (Dirichlet's theorem)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.